# Where / how to obtain the pre-release version of Lodash (3.0.0-pre)

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'd like to leverage the newly added string functions in Lodash, but I'm having trouble finding the pre-release version.

Does pre-release directly track master on Github, or is there another way to get it?  Any indication of the stability of the pre-release version (beyond the fact it's obvious pre-release)?

Comment: It's on github https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/master/lodash.js

Comment: I'm not asking for a recommendation.  I'm asking 1. where can I find this version of the library, 2. whether this version is considered, by the author of the library to be viable for production use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can download...

https://github.com/lodash/lodash

You always have new ver on github...

Comment: Yep, it was a long time :) Link updated...